# R data table outer join by function

Tags: r

I have one data table with the following columns:

```
name, x, y
a, 1, 2
b, 2, 3
c, 3, 1
```

I want to join this table with itself, keeping every row where `name != name` and run a distance function on the `x` and `y` values from each side.  The result should be in the format:

```
name1, name2, distance
```

I wrote the distance function like this:

```
dist <- function(a, b) sqrt((a$x-b$x)^2 + (a$y-b$y)^2)
```

I tried to use the `outer` function, but it only takes vectors, not data tables and I tried using the various joins in dplyr but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Looks like you are just using euclidean distance. I think you just want the `dist()` function to do the calculation. It would be easier to test with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose your dataset looked like:

```
d <- data_frame(name = rownames(mtcars), x = mtcars$mpg, y = mtcars$cyl)
```

A general way to try all combinations of two data frames (or all combinations with themselves) is tidyr's `crossing` function (though you'll need to be careful about renaming the columns). Afterwards you'll be able to compute the distance and do your filtering:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  rename(name1 = name, x1 = x, y1 = y) %>%
  crossing(d) %>%
  rename(name2 = name, x2 = x, y2 = y) %>%
  mutate(distance = sqrt((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2)) %>%
  filter(name1 != name2)
```

In this particular case, you could use my [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package, specifically `distance_join` (you'll need the latest development version from GitHub). This joins two data frames (in this case, a self-join) based on a distance threshold, and appends an additional column with the distance:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

d %>%
  rename(name1 = name) %>%
  distance_inner_join(d, max_dist = Inf, distance_col = "distance") %>%
  rename(name2 = name) %>%
  filter(name1 != name2)
```

This will give:

```
# A tibble: 992 x 7
       name1   x.x   y.x             name2   x.y   y.y distance
       <chr> <dbl> <dbl>             <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1  Mazda RX4    21     6     Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0     6 0.000000
2  Mazda RX4    21     6        Datsun 710  22.8     4 2.690725
3  Mazda RX4    21     6    Hornet 4 Drive  21.4     6 0.400000
4  Mazda RX4    21     6 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8 3.047950
5  Mazda RX4    21     6           Valiant  18.1     6 2.900000
6  Mazda RX4    21     6        Duster 360  14.3     8 6.992138
7  Mazda RX4    21     6         Merc 240D  24.4     4 3.944617
8  Mazda RX4    21     6          Merc 230  22.8     4 2.690725
9  Mazda RX4    21     6          Merc 280  19.2     6 1.800000
10 Mazda RX4    21     6         Merc 280C  17.8     6 3.200000
# ... with 982 more rows
```

You could set `max_dist` to another, non-infinite threshold if you know you don't care about distant matches.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R method that uses `cbind` and `dist` (the function mentioned by @mrflick). we have a data.frame named df created at the bottom of this post.

Note that `dist` returns a lower triangular matrix:

```
dist(df[,-1])
         1        2
2 1.414214         
3 2.236068 2.236068
```

We can use `combn` to create pairwise comparisons of the names variable, then combine the result into a data.frame and give the columns names with `setNames`.

```
dfNew <- setNames(data.frame(t(combn(df$name, 2)),
                             combn(df$name, 2, function(i) {
                                                 dist(df[df$name %in% i, -1])})),
                  c("var1", "var2", "distance"))
```

which returns

```
dfNew
      var1 var2 distance
    1    a    b 1.414214
    2    a    c 2.236068
    3    b    c 2.236068
```

Note that the names variable must be character or you have to wrap it in the the `as.character` function for this to work.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="name, x, y
a, 1, 2
b, 2, 3
c, 3, 1", sep=",", stringsAsFactors=F)
```